# javascript Local Storage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to use local storage for javascript. This is my first time trying local storage. I have two seperate HTML docs each with their own set of javascript code.

Doc 1 Javascript:

```
<script>

function callData() {
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name1");
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name2");
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name3");
setNames();
}

function setNames() {
var 1st = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;
var 2nd = document.getElementById("2").innerHTML;
var 3rd = document.getElementById("3").innerHTML;
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("1", 1st);
    localStorage.setItem("2", 2nd);
    localStorage.setItem("3", 3rd);
}
    else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage"); }
}   

</script>
```

Doc 1 Html

```
<body onLoad = "callData()">
<a style="text-align:left;" href= cameraApp.html>New Contact</a>
<h1 style="background-color:black; color:white; font-family:helvettica;">Address Book</h1>   
<h3 style="background-color:blue; color:white; font-family:helvettica;">Contacts</h3>
<a id=1></a>
<a id=2></a>
<a id=3></a>
</body
```

Doc 2 JavaScript

```
<script>
  function done() {
  var 1st = localStorage.getItem("1");
  var 2nd = localStorage.getItem("2");
  var 3rd = localStorage.getItem("3");

  var name = document.getElementById('nameTextfield').value;


  if(1st = "") {
    localStorage.setItem("name1",name);
    alert("Success, Contact created");
    } else if(2nd = "") {
      localStorage.setItem("name2",name);
      alert("Success, Contact created");
    } else if(3rd = "") {
      localStorage.setItem("name3",name);
      alert("Success, Contact created");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, Maximum contact limit reached");
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
```

Doc 2 HTML

```
<body> 
    <a style="text-align:left;" href= phonebook.html>Back</a>
 <h1 style="background-color:black; color:white; font-family:helvettica;">Create a Contact</h1><br>

<form name="info">

<p id="name">Name: </p><input id="nameTextfield" type="textfield"/><br>

</form>
<button onclick="done()">Done</button>
</form>
</body>
```

The Doc 2 is meant to store the name given by the user and pass it to the Local Storage. Doc 1 is then supposed to display the names that have been stored in the local storage. Whenever I try to use this, after clicking the done button on doc 2 the page just refreshes and when I go back to doc 1 no names are added. I am using the Android SDK for the coding. I have tried using local storage for a hello world document so I know that it works for SDK.

Comment: Is your browser supporting this feature?

Comment: typo => `(typeof(Storage)`

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing this on? Do you test with local files (for which localStorage might not be supported), or with files on a server?

Answer (score 1):

Variable names can't start with numbers (*Correct me if i'm wrong*).

Which is throwing error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.
```

Also, you're checking whether the value exists or not by comparing to empty string (`""`), which will not also work,

You can check it instead like

```
if(!variable){
 //variable does not exist
}
```

fixing these seems to solve the issue

[Doc1](http://jsfiddle.net/T62zZ/)

[Doc2](http://jsfiddle.net/8RutU/)

Comment: Thanks, but there still are two other errors:                                                                                       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'value' of null:66                          sendUserActionEvent()myView == null

Comment: @user3849699 i don't think that is there in the shared code. Whatever you've shared is working in the fiddles i've added...